(Firebase App hosting) Error: Only the Angular application builder is supported
I'm working on an Angular project where I need to use environment variables managed by dotenv. For this, I've been using the custom webpack builder provided by @angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser. This allows me to define my custom webpack configuration and load environment variables from a .env file.
However, I want to deploy my application to Firebase Hosting, which only supports the default Angular application builder (@angular-devkit/build-angular:application). When I try to deploy my project, I get this  Error: Only the Angular application builder is supported.
I tried somehow to add dotenv to @angular-devkit/build-angular:application, but no success.
angular.json:
{
  "projects": {
    "my-angular-app": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "src/custom-webpack.config.ts"
            },
            "outputPath": "dist/my-angular-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": ["src/styles.css"],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-angular-app:build"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


Did you check https://github.com/chihab/dotenv-run?tab=readme-ov-file#ngx-envbuilder?

Yes, I did, still not working.

Please provide more information. What exactly have you tried, and which problem / error did occur? Also the question contains a lot of useless information. For example, we don't need to know the previous angular.json configuration, it's quite clear how it used to work. Please try to focus on the relevant information.

I got build error on the firebase app hosting: Error: Only the Angular application builder is supported. I have tried dotenv-run and dotenv-webpack
